# Using both: Flow Router and Iron Router (Meteor)

Tags: rest, meteor, iron-router, flow-router

Is there anybody uses them both? I need IronRouter for server side, RestApi and Flow Router I was using before, so I can get rid of it but I do not want. 
But I don't like this sh from Iron Router right now for every my Flow Router page.

```
Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url: "http://localhost:3000/."
```

How to do not show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are already familiar with FlowRoute and want `server side` route for your API, you can use `Picker`. It's from the same author of `FlowRouter`. So you should face no problem using along with the flowrouter. and it's also easy to use.

```
https://github.com/meteorhacks/picker
```

Comment: Thanks, can't find better solution. did like you said, picker works fine, but it have taken body-parser to be istalled as well

Comment: but I got new issues with it. when I use it locally it easy to install body-parser via npm command. but when I deployed to modulus.io there are no installed body-parser

Comment: talk with their suppor team.